# Meaning of r.viewshed output numbers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I have completed a r.viewshed analysis of a point in GRASS7. I have imported the arising Geotiff into QGIS and when viewing the layer in the layer window (after expanding the +) I am presented with a number range= Min 88, Max 93.

Can someone please let me know what these numbers relate to?

Comment: Note: Take care to load the actual not estimated range. To do so, go to Layer Properties -> Style -> Accuracy: Actual" -> Load -> Apply/OK

Comment: Since asking my question I have registered on the site. Whilst the user name has changed from user37782 I would like to thank you both for your assistance, you have both been extremely helpful.

Comment: @joverall I recommend that you merge your account with that of user37782 - there is a procedure at http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts describing how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quote from the GRASS manpages for r.viewshed that explains the values:

```
The output raster map may have one of three possible formats, based on which flags are set.


By  default,  if  no  flag  is  set, the output is in angle-mode,
and each point in the output map is marked as NULL if the point is not visible
or the respective point in  the  elevation  map  is  NULL.

    Otherwise,  a  value  in  [0,  180]  representing the vertical angle
with regard to the viewpoint, in degrees, if the point is visible.  
A value of 0 is directly below the specified viewing position,  90 is due horizontal.
The angle to the cell containing the viewing position is undefined and set to 180.

       If the -b flag is set, the output is in boolean-mode, and each point in the output map is marked as:    
           ·   0 if the point is no-data/null or not visible
           ·   1 if the point is visible.

       If  the  -e  flag is set, the output is in elevation-mode, and each point in the output map is marked
       as:
           ·   no-data (null), if the respective point in the elevation map is no-data (null)
           ·   -1, if the point is not visible
           ·   the difference in elevation between the point and the viewpoint, if the point is visible.
```

So your values are probably the angle between the each pixel location and the viewing position.